# Downloading a .flv stream

Tags: cron, http-live-streaming

I am trying to setup a cronjob that will run everyday at a specific time and record an .flv audio stream for an hour and then save the file and quit recording.

I know of a lot of rtmp tools to download such things, but I am unsure if the stream actually is rtmp as using the rtmp protocol in players such as VLC do not work.

In VLC I can play:

`http://live.leanstream.co/CKBTFM?type=.flv&playertype=socast1`

I however cannot play:

`rtmp://live.leanstream.co/CKBTFM?type=.flv&playertype=socast1`

How do I discover what kind of protocol is being used for this stream so that I can find the correct tool.

Edit: It looks like I can actually change the URL so that it gives me a different format such as `.mp3`:

`http://live.leanstream.co/CKBTFM?type=.mp3`

When trying to use tools such as Streamripper or wget I am receiving 404 errors which doesn't make sense as I can listen to the streams from my browser and vlc:

```
$ wget -O stream.mp3 "http://live.leanstream.co/CKBTFM?type=.mp3"
--2015-06-24 13:58:23--  http://live.leanstream.co/CKBTFM?type=.mp3
Resolving live.leanstream.co (live.leanstream.co)... 199.168.112.72
Connecting to live.leanstream.co (live.leanstream.co)|199.168.112.72|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Available
2015-06-24 13:58:24 ERROR 404: Not Available.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ffmpeg` without worrying too much about the protocols and formats since it has an auto-detection feature.

```
ffmpeg -i "http://live.leanstream.co/CKBTFM?type=.flv&playertype=socast1" -t 3600 -f flv out.flv
```

where `-t 3600` is the 1 hour time limit.

If you only need to fetch information about the stream you can use `ffprobe`.

https://www.ffmpeg.org/

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I like that you included the `ffprobe` part as there are times when it is hard to find information about the stream! I also found out another problem is that the streaming site is actually only allowing Canadian IP's to access the stream and therefore my American based server was failing to download from the stream.